# Conflict between passing an Array from Main Class to Function, but also wanting to use return vales from my "getter" method

Tags: java, methods, static, non-static

In my main class, I have a static method which I pass the array into. It is a static method because if I want to pass something from the main class body to this method, it must be static. In a separate class I have a series of getters and setters (which must be non static ).

How can I pass my static array in and use the non-static getters and setters?

EDIT- In the arraySearch method...I cannot pass in the Person Array and access the getters in the Person Class

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Person One = new Person("Alice","Foo", 22, false);
    Person Two = new Person("Alice", "Foo",22, false);
    Person Three = new Person("Bob","Bar",99, false);
    Person Four = new Person("Joe","Blogs",64, false);
    Person Five = new Person("Jane", "Joe",42, false);

    Person [] People = {One,Two,Three,Four,Five};
    printArray(People);

}

public static void printArray(Person [] People)
{
    for(int i=0;i<People.length;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(People[i]);
    }
}


public void arraySearch(Person [] People)
{
    for(int i=0;i<People.length;i++)                                //Searches the Array of Objects
    {
        String firstName = Person.getFirstName();
        String secondName=Person.getSecondName();
        if((firstName.equals("Joe")&&secondName.equals("B" +        //Searches for Joe Blogs and Jane Joe
                "logs"))|| ((firstName.equals("Ja" +
                        "ne")&&secondName.equals("Joe"))))
        {
            int age=Person.getAge();
            Person.setAge(age+1);                                   //Increments Age by 1
        }
    }
}
```

}

public class Person {

```
private String mfirstName;
private  String msecondName;
private  int mage;
private boolean misRetired;

public Person(String firstName,String secondName,int age, boolean isRetired)
{
    mfirstName=firstName;
    msecondName=secondName;
    mage=age;
    misRetired=isRetired;
}

//GETTERS 

public  String getFirstName()
{
    return mfirstName;
}
public  String getSecondName()
{
    return msecondName;
}
public  int getAge()
{
    return mage;
}
public  boolean getRetired()
{
    return misRetired;
}

//SETTERS

public  void setFirstName(String firstName)
{
    mfirstName=firstName;
}
public  void setSecondName(String secondName)
{
    msecondName=secondName;
}
public  void setAge(int age)
{
    mage=age;
}
public  void setRetired(boolean isRetired)
{
    misRetired=isRetired;
}

//STRING

public String toString()
{
    return (mfirstName+"-"+msecondName+"-"+mage+"-"+misRetired);
}
```

}

Comment: Can you show us your codes?

Answer (score 1):

This is very basic Java question. You need to create instance of object containing setter/getters from your static method. You can also pass static array in setter of this object. Then you should be able to call those getter/setter methods.

```
public class Main
{

     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
         MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
         myclass.setArgs(args);
         System.out.println(myclass.getArgs());
     }
}

public class MyClass
{
     private String[] args;

     public String[] getArgs()
     {
         return args;
     }

     public void setArgs(String[] args)
     {
         this.args= args;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an object instance from the class with the getters.

Answer (score 0):

The Amit answer is correct; this just has some more info and more closely matches the situation you describe in your question.

Your basic premise "It is a static method because if I want to pass something from the main class body to this method, it must be static." is wrong.  The method to which you pass the array does not need to be static.  Here is some code:

```
public final class Main
{
    private static final String[] staticOTron =
    {
        "one",
        "two",
        "three"
    };

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        String[] hootBerrySause;
        Tool tool = new Tool();

        tool.setStaticOTron(staticOTron);

        hootBerrySause = tool.getStaticOTron();

        for (String value : hootBerrySause)
        {
            System.out.println("Value: " + value);
        }
    }
}

// this can be in a different file.
public final class Tool
{
    private static String[] staticOTron;

    public void setStaticOTron(final String[] newValue)
    {
        staticOTron = newValue;
    }

    public String[] getStaticOTron()
    {
        return staticOTron;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sunil kumar from vmoksha

Your asking deeper navigation
Just create the instance of particular or create the getter &and setter in the main
class